# How to escape/sanitize a user provided url in twig / symfony?

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, twig, escaping

I'm trying to <strike>escape</strike> sanitize a user provided link in a twig template. I'm using Symfony 5. Initially I started my project in Wordpress but I'm now building it in Symfony. I really liked the Wordpress's function esc_url with which you could escape a user provided link and it would be valid.

Now I know that I can use the escape('url') filter, to escape it. But under the hood this just runs the native php rawurlencode which doesn't sanitize the url.

Example:

This:

```
<a href="{{ 'https://example.com/this/may-be-invalid/'|e('url') }}">SOME URL</a>
```

turns into this:

```html
<a href="https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fthis%2Fmay-be-invalid%2F">SOME URL</a>
```

If the user clicked on this link, they would be taken to: http://localhost/https://example.com/this/may-be-invalid/

Note: localhost can be any domain, just an example.

Example:

```php
<a href="<?= esc_url('https://example.com/this/may-be-invalid/') ?>">SOME URL</a>
```

turns into this:

```html
<a href="https://example.com/this/may-be-invalid/">SOME URL</a>
```

Is there a similar function/filter in Twig or do I have to port the Wordpress's esc_url to my project non Wordpress?

How can I sanitize a user provided url in Twig/Symfony?

Edit: Updated the question based on @DarkBee's comment

Comment: It seems `esc_url` is actualy sanitazing the url, not escaping it. You could just chain the `esc_url` function in `twig`. No need to port it, e.g. `$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\Filter('esc_url', 'esc_url', [ 'is_safe' => 'html', ]));`

Comment: @DarkBee Right, mixed the sanitization and escaping, will update the question. However, I'm not using Twig with Wordpress I'm starting a new project, that will use the Symfony framework.

Comment: Well you should be able to register extra functions/filters in a config file somewhere though. Don't know the details on howto in symfony though

Comment: @DarkBee I mean esc_url is a Wordpress function, the new project doesn't have any Wordpress code, so the only way to register the filter is to copy the esc_url function from WP and then include it like you suggested. I was looking for a potential native twig function to achieve the same thing

Comment: Ah like that, no twig doesn't have this built-in, but i see the [sourcecode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) is just online, so u could copy it

Comment: @DarkBee Ok, thank you, I was looking for the confirmation that twig does not support this natively